# What means FP in CrUX Community Dashboard?

Tags: chrome-ux-report

CrUX Community Dashboard provides on the page 7 metric named FP / First Paint. But I can't find at web.dev any metric with this name.

However, under web.dev there is a metric named First Meaningful Pant. On comparing First Paint and First Meaningful Paint, one realizes,

- First Paint on the page 7 of CrUX Dashboard has following ranges: `Good (< 1s), Poor (>= 3s)`,
- while First Meaningful Paint's ranges, listed at web.dev, are: `Good (< 2s), Poor (>= 4s)`.

Is it an error in the CrUX Community Dashboard and Firts Paint should be First Meaningful Paint? Or miss I something?

Answer (score 1):

CrUX metrics are defined in more detail in the official docs, for example [First Paint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/#first-paint) is defined as:

> First Paint reports the time when the browser first rendered after navigation. This excludes the default background paint, but includes non-default background paint. This is the first key moment developers care about in page load – when the browser has started to render the page.
>
> — [Paint Timing API](https://w3c.github.io/paint-timing/#first-paint)

See https://web.dev/first-meaningful-paint/ for more info on FMP, which is now a deprecated metric.

Also see this related answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47788460/1022333

Comment: There is no any information about limits for good, ni and bad FP. Do you know, where FP limits are listed?

Comment: The same as with `FP` happens with the rest of metrics: `OnLoad` and `DOM Content Load`: there is no information about their good and bad limits - however, these limits are placed in the CrUX Dashboard. Where are origins of these limits?

Comment: The thresholds are assigned subjectively by each tool in the absence of widely accepted thresholds, for example those set by the Core Web Vitals program (LCP, FID, CLS)