# Performance - "First paint" vs "First Contentful Paint"

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, web-vitals

In Chrome devTools performance tab, on the profiling result page both "FP" and "FCP" are appearing in the timeline.
[image]

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['time to first paint' vs 'First Meaningful Paint'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209419/time-to-first-paint-vs-first-meaningful-paint)

Comment: Thanks @SuperStormer, It can be but I'm not sure. I found this article but it says "FP" is "The first paint action of the browser, from the browser own perspective. Not necessarily visible from a human."
It's different from "The time when the first pixel is painted onto the screen."
Can't find a reliable source!

link: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2019/09/first-contentful-paint-fcp/